# Reopening last known open bootstrap modal after page refresh when paginating

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal, codeigniter-4

So I have a link that opens a bootstrap 4 modal. The modal has data that users can paginate through. My problem is that when user paginates. The entire page is refreshed and the bootstrap popup is not reloaded.

I have applied something similar on last know open tab using localstorage and would like help implementing the same thing for modals. I want to track which modal was last open before page reloads so that when page is done reloading the modal that was open should show again.

Code i used for Tabs is as follows :

```
<script>
  // A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).modal('show');
});

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href");
    localStorage.setItem('selectedTab', id)
});

var selectedTab = localStorage.getItem('selectedTab');
if (selectedTab != null) {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"][href="' + selectedTab + '"]').tab('show');
}

});
</script>
```

could you help me implement the above code to remeber and reopen last known modal. My modal codes are something like this.

```
<div id="form-payments">
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried the following but i know for some reason I'm missing something because when i try to paginate it does not respond but if i refresh page current modal does load when page refreshed but it does not click the pagination tab.

```
<script>
  // A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('div[data-target="modal"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).modal('show');
});

$('div[data-target="modal"]').on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("id");
    localStorage.setItem('openModal', id)
});

var openModal = localStorage.getItem('openModal');
if (openModal != null) {
    $('div[data-target="modal"] [id="' + openModal + '"]').modal('show');
}

});
</script>
```